Spring boot upgrade from 3.1.9 to 3.2.3 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager cannot be null
I am upgrading my spring boot project from 3.1.9 to 3.2.3, I am getting error while running the tests. Found that below line of code is causing the issue.
httpsecurity.anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
Below is the exception stack trace
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.test.AuthenticationPropertiesTest
                                                                                                                            
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
2024-04-24T10:41:55.505+05:30  INFO 24448 --- [           main] org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager          : Cache 'authenticationCache' created in EhcacheManager.
10:41:56.565 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/sample/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: authenticationManager cannot be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:895) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:848) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:959) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1454) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225) ~[spring-test-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152) ~[spring-test-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130) ~[spring-test-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191) ~[spring-test-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130) ~[spring-test-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260) ~[spring-test-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163) ~[spring-test-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:378) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:383) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:378) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:290) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:279) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:198) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141) [junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57) [junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103) [junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:85) [junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:47) [junit-platform-launcher-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:56) [surefire-junit-platform-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:184) [surefire-junit-platform-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:148) [surefire-junit-platform-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:122) [surefire-junit-platform-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385) [surefire-booter-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162) [surefire-booter-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507) [surefire-booter-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495) [surefire-booter-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/sample/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: authenticationManager cannot be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:639) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1689) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1653) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeanCollection(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1543) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1511) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1392) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:887) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    ... 98 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: authenticationManager cannot be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:177) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:647) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:639) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1689) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1653) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeanCollection(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1543) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1511) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1392) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:887) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    ... 98 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager cannot be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:172) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.<init>(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.HttpBasicConfigurer.configure(HttpBasicConfigurer.java:211) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.HttpBasicConfigurer.configure(HttpBasicConfigurer.java:83) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:376) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:330) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
    at com.sample.WebSecurityConfig.filterChain(WebSecurityConfig.java:85) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.sample.WebSecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$filterChain$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.sample.WebSecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$1.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at com.sample.audit.WebSecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.filterChain(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:140) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:647) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:639) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1689) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1653) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeanCollection(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1543) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1511) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1392) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:887) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    ... 98 more

And SecurityFilterChain configuration as below
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.securityContext(a->a.requireExplicitSave(false))
               .authorizeHttpRequests(a->a.dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll());
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).sessionManagement(a->a.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS));
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(a->a.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").hasAnyAuthority(getAppPermissions())
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/**").hasAnyAuthority(getAppPermissions())
                .anyRequest().denyAll())
                .anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .exceptionHandling(b->b.accessDeniedPage("/unauthorized"));
        http.httpBasic(a->a.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint));
        http.headers(a->a.addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Content-Security-Policy",getContentSecurityPolicy())));
       
        return http.build();
    }

From the above code if I comment .anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable) the build is successful, Please let me know if I am missing anything as commenting it is not a solution for me.

strong textWhen running tests authenticator seems null, so calling init method fixed the issue  .anonymous(a->a.init(http))
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
            http.securityContext(a->a.requireExplicitSave(false))
                   .authorizeHttpRequests(a->a.dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll());
            http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).sessionManagement(a->a.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS));
            http.authorizeHttpRequests(a->a.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").hasAnyAuthority(getAppPermissions())
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/**").hasAnyAuthority(getAppPermissions())
                    .anyRequest().denyAll())
                    .anonymous(a->a.init(http))
                    .anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .exceptionHandling(b->b.accessDeniedPage("/unauthorized"));
            http.httpBasic(a->a.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint));
            http.headers(a->a.addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Content-Security-Policy",getContentSecurityPolicy())));
           
            return http.build();
        }

